# Converting ConfigParser values to python data types

Tags: python, eval, configparser

`ConfigParser` requires all sections, keys and values to be strings; no surprise. It has methods to convert the values to datatypes with `getfloat`, `getint`, `getboolean`.  If you don't know the datatype, you can wrap the `get()` with an `eval()` to get have the string evaluated such as:

```
>>> from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
>>> cp = SafeConfigParser()
>>> cp.add_section('one')
>>> cp.set('one', 'key', '42')
>>> print cp.get('one', 'key')
'42'
>>> print eval(cp.get('one', 'key'))
42
>>> cp.set('one', 'key', 'None')
>>> print eval(cp.get('one', 'key'))
None
>>>
```

Is there a better way? I assume there some grave security concerns with evaluating text from a file- which I acknowledge; I completely trust the file.

I thought I would use `pickle` for this, but I would really like to keep the config file human readable.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.6 or above you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>   Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

This will work like `eval` when the string is safe:

```
>>> literal_eval("{'key': 10}")
{'key': 10}
```

But it will fail if anything besides the types listed in the documentation appear:

```
>>> literal_eval("import os; os.system('rm -rf somepath')")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    import os; os.system('rm -rf somepath')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: i used your answer to create this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/python-subclassing-configparser

Answer (score 5):

For those that may be looking for another easier answer, instead of having to convert the data types yourself, you can use the [localconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/localconfig) module that does the conversion for you. The conversion is done by guessing the data type based on the value (I.e. 123 is an int, 123.4 is a float, true is a bool, and so on).

Here is an example following the OP's:

```
>>> from localconfig import config
>>> config.read('[one]\nkey = 42\nkey2 = None')
>>> config.one.key, type(config.one.key)
(42, <type 'int'>)
>>> config.one.key2, type(config.one.key2)
(None, <type 'NoneType'>)
>>> config.get('one', 'key'), config.get('one', 'key2')
(42, None)
```

It is a wrapper on top of ConfigParser, so it is fully compatible.

Check it out at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/localconfig

Comment: Thanks, your packages was very helpful for me!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an another solution. You can generate a `getany()` method that will automatically detect and return the correct data type for most types including `str`, `int`, `float`, `bool` and `None`.

Note that the notation in the config file needs to be Python for this to work. e.g. `True` for boolean true and `None` for null values.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import configparser

parser = configparser.ConfigParser(converters={"any": lambda x: literal_eval(x)})
value = parser.getany("section", "key")
# ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for simple string values, does it? `key=1.0` is fine, but `key=test` isn't...

Comment: yes. As mentioned it only works for values in Python notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 2.7+ then you can use the `.getint` `.getfloat` `.getbool` methods. You can learn more about them in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getint)

So your application would use `print cp.getint('one', 'key')`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout ConfigIt for more pythonic configuration options

https://github.com/barberj/ConfigIt

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Erik Kalkoken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66145371/5571212). You can probably write a converter function which gives you more control over how you want to evaluate the value.

```py
def converter(in_str: str):
    try:
        out = literal_eval(in_str)
    except Exception:
        out = in_str
    return out

parser = configparser.ConfigParser(converters={"any": lambda x: converter(x)})
value = parser.getany("section", "key")
```